# react-native how to import project root directory?

Tags: react-native

```
App
 |-- application
      |-- config 
      |    |-- themes.js
      |    |-- redux.js
      +-- views
      |    |-- login
      |    |    |-- login.js  
      |-- index.js
```

index.js

```
....
import themes from './config/themes';
import themes from './config/redux';
...
```

login.js

```
....
import themes from '../../config/themes';
import themes from '../../config/redux';
...
```

I hope it like this:

```
....
import themes from '@root/application/config/themes';
import themes from '@root/application/config/redux';
import ... from '@root/...';
...
```

if methods of php

```
$root = 'User/React-Native-Project/';
include $root.'/application/config/themes.php';
```

This can improve the development efficiency and avoid the wrong path and other issues.my english is not good.

Comment: For future readers, the babel plugin referenced in the accepted answer below is outdated. It was `babel-plugin-module-alias`and now it's `babel-plugin-module-resolver`. See this [link](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#updating-from-babel-plugin-module-alias) for more info.

Comment: @Héctor, I just provided an updated and more concise answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Alias in React Native**
There is a point where you will have multiple files and folder in  your project. And we need to get the reference of one file from another in any random possibilities.  If we are following the relative path such as

```
import themes from '../../config/themes';
```

then it’s really very hard for us to get an idea where it takes by the symbol ‘**../** ‘  and in more complex project this is a night mare.

In this post we will find the possible solution and alternative on this type of scenario.  Let’s take an example project with following folder structure.

```
Your App Root Directory
 |-- app
      |-- component 
      |    |-- login
      |    |   |-- login.js
      +-- resources
      |    |-- icon
      |    |    |-- userupload.png  
 |-- index.ios.js
 |-- index.android.js
```

We have two possible solution to point each node in the above folder structure.

**Use @providesModule** (***update:*** will not work for RN versions 56 and above.  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21152)

A secondary solution that would work but is less “safe”, is to use @providesModule in your file. This comes with less boilerplate but since it’s based on Facebook’s own internal use case, it could change based on their internal whim. You can read more about it here:https://github.com/facebook/fbjs

To use it you need to include this comment at the top of your file:

```
/**
 * @providesModule login
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 AppRegistry,
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View
} from 'react-native';

export default class login extends Component{
 render(){
 return(
 <View>
 <Text> this is login page
 </Text>
 </View>
 );
 }
}
```

Then you can import it the same as above:

```
import themes from 'login';
```

**Use babel-plugin-module-alias**

A babel plugin to rewrite (map, alias, resolve) directories as different directories during the Babel process. It’s particularly useful when you have files you don’t want to use with relative paths (especially in big projects).

Uses:

Install babel cli

```
npm install --g babel-cli
```

Install  babel-plugin-module-alias.

$ `npm install --save babel babel-plugin-module-alias`

Create a file .babelrc in root directory or add  a key babel:   your project’s package.json and add following lines of code.

```
"babel":{
  "plugins": [[
    "module-alias", [
      { "src": "./app", "expose": "app" },
      { "src": "./app/resources/icon", "expose": "icon" }
      ]
   ]]
 }
```

and finally clear the cache and restart the node server

```
 npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Full source code can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/tigerraj32/ReactNative/)

Comment: 'babel-plugin-module-alias' is now outdated... new version is 'babel-plugin-module-resolver'. I left a comment for reference on the OP question, but you might want to update this answer as well.

Answer (score 11):

use babel-plugin-module-alias

```
npm install --save babel babel-plugin-module-alias
```

create a `.babelrc` file for project root directory.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-module-alias", [
      { "src": "./application", "expose": "app" }
    ]]
  ]
}
```

start command:

```
   npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Now we can do the:

```
....
import themes from 'app/config/themes';
import themes from 'app/config/redux';
import ... from 'app/...';
...
```

Comment: I don't think it isnt working.. https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/issues/29

Comment: `babel-plugin-module-alias` is now `babel-plugin-module-resolver`

Answer (score 11):

### Use [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

*The existing answers were long-winded, outdated and made it way more complicated than it needs to be. I felt obligated to add a succinct answer to help others.*

1. Install the package:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev --save-exact babel-plugin-module-resolver
   ```
2. Modify or create a `.babelrc` file in your root directory with the following:

   ```
   {
     "plugins": [
       [ "module-resolver", { "root": ["./"] } ] 
     ]
   }
   ```

   You can change `./` to the root of your code, like `./application` or something.
3. Update your `import` paths:

   Instead of writing:

   ```
   import themes from '../../config/themes';
   ```

   You can write this:

   ```
   import themes from 'config/themes';
   ```
4. Profit!

Comment: Excellent solution. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can create a package.json file containing {"name": "root"} in your root folder. Note that this may be a different file than the original 'package.json' that every project has.

And in case you want to use another folder named X populate the package.json with {"name": "X"}. so now you can simply use `import foo from 'X/foo'` in your project.

For more information check these:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099#issuecomment-221815006
https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 solutions to accomplish what you want:

**1) Create a "themes" package**

One thing that's nice about the React Native packager is that it will pick up any "packages" (or "node modules") that are anywhere in your project directory structure.

This means that in your `config` directory, you could have a `themes` directory with a `package.json` (with a "name" field of 'themes') and an `index.js` (the `index.js` would contain the code that you now have in 'application/config/themes'.)

Then, when you want to import this code you can simply do:

`import themes from 'themes';`

Remember, you can place this "package" anywhere you want in your directory structure. While this isn't "exactly" what you were looking for, it is definitely a working solution.

**2) Use @providesModule**(***update:*** will not work for RN versions 56 and above. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21152)

A secondary solution that would work but is less "safe", is to use `@providesModule` in your file. This comes with less boilerplate but since it's based on Facebook's own internal use case, it could change based on their internal whim. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/facebook/fbjs

To use it you need to include this comment at the top of your file:

```
/**
 * @providesModule themes
 */
```

Then you can import it the same as above:

`import themes from 'themes';`

Here is an example of it being used in the React Native project itself: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Text/Text.js#L9

Comment: Thank you very much, but that's not what I need.

Comment: I hope that the relative path into an absolute path. Such import documents would be more convenient to react-native, the same time avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

This actually isn't really about React Native. I think that it's more of a Babel question. The answer is actually quite simple—use the [Module Resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) package. This allows one to configure a module-specifier-to-URL resolver for use by Babel. It's especially useful for avoiding relative URLs.

First, execute the following command:

```bsh
$ npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

Then, in your ".babelrc" file or in a `babel` attribute of your project's "package.json" file, specify the options for the plugin:

```json
"plugins": [[
  "module-resolver", {
    "root": ["./application"]
  }
]]
```

Finally, clear the cache and restart the node server

```bash
$ npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: I don't think it works.. https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/issues/29

Comment: Have you tried all of the suggestions in there? It looks like several people in that issue were able to get it to work through various means.

Comment: I couldn't figure out to import files from outside of RN project root. I 'm copying files to RN_ROOT/node_modules/ ... sad it's the best I can do.

Comment: Since you're taking that approach, why don't you just set up a symbolic link of some sort?

Answer (score -1):

To use the babel plugin, you need the babel-preset-react-native :

1. Add babel-preset-react-native:

   `$ npm i --save-dev babel-preset-react-native babel-plugin-module-alias`
2. Add .babelrc

```

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-alias", [
      { "src": "./app", "expose": "app" }
    ]]
  ]
}
```

```

3. react-native run-ios

See:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-native

https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-alias