# reactjs how to import project root directory?

Tags: reactjs

react-native : [react-native how to import project root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003898/react-native-how-to-import-project-root-directory)

But, I want to do on react.

```
App
 |-- application
      |-- config 
      |    |-- themes.js
      |    |-- redux.js
      +-- views
      |    |-- login
      |    |    |-- login.js  
      |-- index.js
```

examples:

```
....
import themes from './config/themes';
import themes from './config/redux';
...

....
import themes from '../../config/themes';
import themes from '../../config/redux';
...
```

This is the code:

```
....
import themes from '@root/application/config/themes';
import themes from '@root/application/config/redux';
import ... from '@root/...';
...
```