# react test import deeply nested components

Tags: reactjs, testing, import

I have a `React` app. The folders looks like this:

```
├── src
│   ├── App.jsx
│   └── components
│       ├── charts
│       │   ├── Chart.jsx
│       └── editor
│           └── Editor.jsx
│
├── test
│   └── testComponents
│       ├── testCharts
│       │   └── testChart.js
│       └── testEditor
│           └── testEditor.js
│
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

Because the folders are deep, the `import` inside `testChart.js` looks like:

```
import Chart from './../../../src/components/charts/Chart.jsx'

// ...codes...
```

The `./../../../src/ ...` is not very friendly I think. Is there any way to make it more clean like `import charts/Charts.jsx`?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003898/react-native-how-to-import-project-root-directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give alias to Component files in webpack

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: It works, thanks! Seems I need more time to understand webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the accepted answer, to be more clear:

```
// webpack.config.js
// ...
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      srcDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
    }
  }
}
```

Then in `testChart.js`, you could directly import `srcDir` as following.

```
import Chart from 'srcDir/components/charts/Chart.jsx'
```